# I want to retrieve data with firebase firestore where query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

[image]

This is my database. I want to get the displaynames of the users. With this data, I want to search their names in an input and show their data.
This is the code I wrote

```
const belgeRef = collection(db, "users"); // Belge referansını oluşturun
        
const sorgu = query(
  belgeRef,
  where("displayName", ">=", inputValue),
  where("displayName", "<=", inputValue + "\uf8ff")
);

getDocs(sorgu)
  .then((querySnapshot) => {
    const bulunanKullanicilar = [];
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
      const belgeVerileri = doc.data();
      const kullaniciAdi = belgeVerileri.data[0].displayName;
      console.log(belgeVerileri)
      bulunanKullanicilar.push(kullaniciAdi);
    });
    setVeriler(bulunanKullanicilar);
    
    console.log("Bulunan Kullanıcılar:", bulunanKullanicilar);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error("Hata:", error);
  });
```

I want to access the data inside my users' documents within the collection

Comment: Do you get an error? You should see an error indicating that you need to create a composite index and containing an HTTP link that will trigger this creation.

Comment: The code looks fine at first glance, so what isn't working as expected about it? As Renaud also asked: is there an error message? If not, did you debug the code yet? If you `console.log("'"+inputValue+"'")`, what does it show? What do the out `console.log` statements in your code output?

Comment: It looks like you've got your user properties stored in an array within your document? `users/document/data array/array index 0/user properties` etc. That's too deep for your query. e.g. the query is for `users/document/display name` but the structure is `users/document/data/array`. Can you just make the properties as properties of the document itself instead of being buried inside an array within the document? e.g. your structure needs to be shallower for that query

Comment: No, I do not get any errors, the data comes to the console, but when I create a query, I cannot pull the data, an empty array is returned.

Comment: The console log prints the data in the database to the screen and it is successful, but when I add the query block, it returns an empty array. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: There is an input value and I checked its value with the console log.

Comment: I used the arrayunion command while adding the data and saved the data in the database in this way because when I add it normally, when the displayName is updated, all of them are updated and their values become null.

Comment: What does the `console.log(belgeVerileri)` output? Please **don't** include this in a comment, but edit your question to include this information.

Comment: I am Turkish and some of the data names are in Turkish. I write the document data to the console where you specified, as I mentioned in my previous comment, I can print the data to the console, but I cannot filter it. @FrankvanPuffelen

Comment: It's not filtering because the query does not match the structure of the data. The query is on `users/document id` and expects each document to have a direct property of `displayName`. The documents only have a property `data` which contains an array. See my above comment.

Comment: SOLVED As jay said, I changed the data path in the database and this solved my problem, thank you.